Hotkey for moving windows
Tell me pls, is there an option to bind a hotkey for transferring the active window between monitors? On Windows there is a hotkey WIN+SHIFT+arrow right left. And on KUBUNTU, KDE?

You've not provided any release details; but Kubuntu uses kwin by default so use the kwin shortcuts - https://docs.kde.org/stable5/en/khelpcenter/fundamentals/kbd.html plus any additional ones specific to your unstated release.

I am running Kubuntu 24.04, and while there does not appear to be a shortcut by default, you can set one.

Open System Settings
Click on Shortcuts
Click on KWin
Scroll down to "Window to Screen 0", etc.
Click on Add custom shortcut
Enter the desired key combination
Click Apply

